Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'. finished with non-zero exit value 1
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1629

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.



Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Can someone please help me solve this issue. I have been trying to fix it for two days. It happened when I upgraded to the new android studio.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
